# How to add a word to the end of a line in bash?

Tags: bash, cpu-word

In the following code we are adding words one under the other. I want to add at the end of a line

```
doc_in=$1 #document to read
main_d=$2 #dictionary of words   
ignored_d=$3 #other dictionary of words    
doc_out=$4 #document to write

word="example"        

function consult_user() { 
    echo "word not found:[$word] Accept (a) - Discard (i) - Replace (r):"

    read opt
    if [ $opt == "a" ]
    then    
        #Here I want to add at the end of a line and not "echo"
        echo $word >>$doc_out # me agrega todo con un \n 
    elif [ $opt == "i" ]
    then
        echo $word >>$ignored_d
    else 
        read new_w
        echo $new_w >>$doc_out
    fi
}

consult_user
```

Comment: So this is basically a spelling checker and you want to write out a copy of the input document with some words removed and some words replaced, without changing the folding of lines?  Your code in isolation doesn't make much sense, and if I'm guessing correctly, you need to change much of the surrounding code before you can get what you ask for.

Comment: `echo word >>file` adds a newline after `word`.  So you would have to have the *previous* echo omit the newline to get another word on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` command to get it done.

```
   sed -i -e "s/$/$word/" $doc_out

[root@client1 ~]# word=example
[root@client1 ~]# doc_out=test
[root@client1 ~]# cat $doc_out
Test Line1
Test Line2
Test Line3
Test Line4
[root@client1 ~]# sed -e "s/$/ $word/" $doc_out
Test Line1 example
Test Line2 example
Test Line3 example
Test Line4 example
```

Comment: It gives me an error: "can not read file: No such file or directory"